# Adding a "Bounty Hunter" badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, bounty

I apologize in advance if this question seems frivolous.

Is adding badges up for discussion?  If so, would the community be receptive to a "Bounty Hunter" badge?  For example, it could be a gold badge awarded for earning 10 bounties.  (Thanks Eric - gold does sound more reasonable than silver.)

[EDIT] Maybe also a bronze badge for "first bounty earned"?

Comment: I think this should probably be posed on meta.stack, since it is a site change.  Do you want to pose it there, or shall I?  (As I said, I think it is a great idea!)

Comment: @Eric Please feel free to move this to meta.stack.  Thanks for the support!

Comment: I don't think I can move things. (How then vote to close)  I'll flag it so a moderator can.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are four already:

https://math.stackexchange.com/badges

- Altruist, First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question
- Benefactor, First bounty you manually awarded on your own question
- Investor, First bounty you offered on another person's question
- Promoter, First bounty you offered on your own question

While bounty is an important tool for getting more attention for your questions, I am not sure we want to put *too* much emphasis on it.

Comment: @Jeff: From the phrasing, it seems Elliott is suggesting badges to people who *earn* bounties, rather than people who offer or award bounties.

Comment: I believe Elliott was referring to badges for bounty winners, not givers.

Comment: @asaf bounty winners already get something -- the reputation from the bounty! Why heap more incentive on top of that?

Comment: @Jeff: I don't know, personally the bounty is not the right incentive. The question is what interests me.

Comment: @Jeff I agree, but at the same time, answers with 25 upvotes result in a badge--one could say "why heap more incentive on top of 250 reputation?"

Comment: @Asaf Absolutely, the question is what's important.  I see the bounty system as a way for people to call attention to a question they find interesting (much more so than an upvote).  Why not have a badge to recognize those who consistently provide high quality responses to such calls?

Comment: @Elliott:  I think this is a really good idea.  A gold bounty hunter badge would be a great addition.  (I say gold because who actually gets 10 bounties?)  @Jeff:  I think there are major flaws in what you say about "Why heap more incentive" and "_too_ much emphasis".  Usually the answers to the bounty questions are some of the best around.  There is currently no badge for answering bounties.

Comment: Are some folks  motivated by the badges? The only discussion I can recall here on them is how silly some folks thought they were.

Comment: @Bill: I'll admit that I find getting badges (without manipulating the system, of course) really satisfying.  That said, of course learning and teaching mathematics is the real reason for using this site.  I think any user that was *primarily* motivated by getting badges would quickly give up and and go play video games or something.